# Production Environment for Yeoman-angular generator

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

I have an app that is running using grunt for development.

Shifting this to a production environment, though, it's apparently not recommended to use Grunt.

With the yeoman team's angular generator, what do I need to do to get my app ready for production?

grunt serve:dist doesn't work (because the file names and paths are obviously different than development).

Comment: depends on how the build process is set  up.

Comment: What info do you need?